# VBA loop through all the values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am self learning VBA and stumbling upon obstacles. Here's one -

I need to loop through an entire column (or till whatever is the last value in that column which will be not known) of a workbook B and the code I am writing in workbook A. I searched through net and got a code which does similar thing

```
 http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=110928
```

code snippet posted by rbrhodes is as follows -

```
 ' Loop on each value (cell)
  For Each Cel In LookRange 
     ' Get value to find
    CelValue = Cel.Value 
     ' Look on sheet2
    With Sheet2
```

But my problem is that I need to split the value in column X of Workbook A in two based on a delimiter and then browse through the entire column Y of Workbook B. Afterwards concatenate the looked upon word (from workbook B) and then check that against column X1 in Workbook A. I thought of using

```
Split(CelValue, "_")
```

But I'm getting error as Type mismatched as CelValue is Variant and

```
CelValStr = CStr(CelValue)
```

isn't working!
Can anyone please help me with this seemingly silly question for all the experts out there?

Thank you!

Comment: `Split` returns an array which can't be passed to a `String` data type or coerced to string using `CStr` function. Do you need both "parts" of the split string, or only one of them? If one, which one?

Comment: Also what are the values in CelValue. Also it is good practice to correctly spell the word Cell (with two L's)

Comment: " I need to split the value in column X of Workbook A in two based on a delimiter " - look at the Data, Text To Columns command. If you record a macro while you do it manually you'll get code you can adapt